# Should iText be using Stack Overflow as a bug reporting system?

Tags: discussion, outsourcing, product-support

I just found [this](http://itextpdf.com/support) on the iText web site (when looking for support with a problem I found):

> - I think I found a bug and I have code that reproduces it! - Post your Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example on StackOverflow. If we determine that it is indeed a bug, then we will add it to our bug tracker.

But I thought that Stack Overflow was for asking questions that could be answered by other developers, not for reporting bugs in 3rd party systems? Is this an abuse of Stack Overflow or have I misunderstood what Stack Overflow is for? If it is an abuse, can anything be done to push back on iText and encourage them to provide a separate reporting tool for their own product?

They also recommend checking against Stack Overflow's iText and iTextSharp topics - but I don't think they control these? - and a new iText7 topic has since been introduced (at my request as it happens), which presumably they are not yet monitoring because they didn't know about it!

Comment: No, they shouldn't. Instead, they should open the 'Issues' page on their GitHub repositories.

Comment: I sort of understand the sentiment.  A lot of users will post bugs that aren't actually problems with the library, but with their code.  A lot of maintainers don't want to do Q&A and support for other's code on the issue tracker.  Posting on SO encourages them to make an MCVE and lets the community identify issues and workarounds.

Comment: A majority of the bugs that are reported aren't bugs but wrong use. Do you want me to make a list of questions that were initially announced as "a bug", but that received a perfectly fine answer on StackOverflow?

Comment: We opened the issue tracker on GitHub, and only got support questions. So we had to close it again.

Comment: The `itext7` tag was created by me, on your request. I am QA Engineer at iText Software. We have an integration between StackOverflow and Slack: every time a new question is asked that is tagged with `itext` or `itext7`, we get a notification in Slack.

Comment: FYI I'm planning a blog post on the iText blog, where I explain our integration between StackOverflow and Slack, and what our workflow and toolset is.

Comment: To explain a bit further, I take the RSS feed http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/itextsharp+or+itext+or+itext7+or+itextpdf+or+itextg+or+xmlworker+or+htmlworker and use Slack's RSS app to have it post to a channel called `#slackoverflow`. This is what it looks like in my browser: http://imgur.com/cULnzJy

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse I still can't see any mention of the iText7 tag on the iText support page that I referenced above?

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse "We opened the issue tracker on GitHub... we had to close it again." I don't see how that makes it Stack Overflow's problem.

Comment: To the OP @DanKing: is your question sufficiently answered? Is there anything else regarding the iText website that I can help you with?

Comment: Pondering if I should flag this question with *The problem described here can no longer be reproduced. Changes to the system or to the circumstances affecting the asker have rendered it obsolete. If you encounter a similar problem, please post a new question.* ;-)

Comment: If I had a dime for every Microsoft bug I diagnosed and found a workaround for then I would be, erm, less poor.  Microsoft doesn't have to tell their customers to ask for help at SO, they can figure that out for themselves.  It is only the small companies with few customers that need to post these notices.  It is never been that clear to me why it is okay for the big ones to spin off support to SO and not for the small ones.  It ought to be the other way around.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse no you should open a bug in your issue tracker "iText web site incorrectly refers users to file bug reports at Stack Overflow" and close it as fixed with note that misleading statement was removed from site

Comment: The SO rules on this subject clearly state "assume good faith" so I will ignore the above comment. I wish to thank everyone who gave a constructive contribution. You're the best!

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse - in response to your last question: I think it's all covered now, thanks! My basic issue was that it felt like your site was telling me to do one thing, which I thought was contrary to what Stack Overflow wanted me to do. I still think it would be helpful if there was somewhere that non-paying iText users could post an obvious bug report, but I do understand the problems you've mentioned with your GitHub issues page.

Comment: @HansPassant I think the difference is that most people assume that the problem is in their own code when it comes to big companies, while they are quicker to assume it's a bug in product when it comes to smaller companies.

Answer (score 76):

Bug reports aren't questions, and users shouldn't be directed to Stack Overflow to post their bug reports. No matter if there is a MCVE or not, if you suspect there is a bug, it has to be reported to the creators directly, by whatever means they provide.

Now, this doesn't mean that you can't happen upon a bug when posting your valid question. But if you suspect and are able to reproduce a bug, Stack Overflow is not where you post it.

Not to mention the fact that most users, even when told to post an MVCE, will still end up posting poorly formulated bug reports because "the site said so". It probably won't end well.

So overall iText should update their website and provide their own proper bug-reporting solution.

Comment: Duly noted, the paragraph about bugs will be removed.

Comment: The short period we had an issue tracker on GitHub, we only had support questions that should have been asked on StackOverflow. When we politely closed the issues and referred to StackOverflow, people got angry. Because of this abuse, we closed the GitHub issues again.

Comment: Apart from that we also have a JIRA issue tracker, for paying customers.

Comment: Sounds like you can't win that one. :(

Answer (score 19):

No, this is not allowed. You can use Stack Overflow to [support your product](https://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support), but:

> #### Types of questions and where to ask:
>
> - I got this error and I'm sure it's a bug -- file an issue (on your own site)

But I understand why they do this - a lot of 'bugs' are actually wrong uses of the library. Creating an MCVE helps in identifying this. Their support text should actually read:

> I think I found a bug and I have code that reproduces it! - Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example and post it on our site. If we determine that it is indeed a bug, then we will add it to our bug tracker.

Oh, and by the way, it is *Stack Overflow* and not *StackOverflow*.

Comment: The text now reads *I have a coding problem and I have code that reproduces it! - Post your Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example on StackOverflow. If we determine that it's not a coding problem, but an actual bug, then we will add it to our bug tracker.*

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse Your updated text still points them to post their bugs to Stack Overflow. That's the entire reason we're having this conversation. The policy here **you can't do that**.

Comment: It is my personal point of view that the paragraph should be removed entirely or be merged with the one above it, with no mention of the word "bug" at all.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse: Well done! I'm bookmarking this to be an example for other sites who refer to Stack Overflow in their Support page.

Answer (score -7):

Whether or not they **should** or **shouldn't** is irrelevant.

When solving a problem you should only consider the variables that you can control. Whether or not a 3rd party says "Go post memes on `stackoverflow.com`" is not something the SO community can control.

If a 3rd party figures out a way to use Stack Overflow as a systematic tool to lessen their support load, then great, they're being resourceful. And if they send their users to SO without the proper guidance, who won't be able to solve their problem on SO, then that's ok too! We have the systems in place to handle that content, and hopefully they have the systems in place to handle unhappy users.

In other words, if they send users here with questions SO can't answer, we can't force them to stop doing that, but we can delete the poor content. And if they send users here with questions that SO *can* answer, then it isn't a problem at all. Last I checked, the off-topic reasons didn't include

> "Where you referred here by a third party lazily trying to handle their
>   support queue?"

Comment: There is so much wrong in this answer that it's difficult to know where to begin: - “you should only consider the variables that you can control”: what do you think this question is? - “then that's ok too!”: actually if you read just a few posts on meta.SO you may notice a recurring theme that experienced valuable users are fatigued of being “the systems” and that post quality is going down the drain

Comment: @PascalCuoq **Simple, clear fact:** SO **cannot** force a 3rd party to stop incorrectly directing users here with questions that aren't meant for SO. It's a variable that we do not control. Clear, simple logic. You can complain about it on meta all you want, but if you complain about a problem that can't be solved, you're just screaming at a wall. It won't change anything.

Comment: I think you are overestimating what SE "does". Stack Exchange (the firm) has enough reputation amongst software developers that *any* direct mail from them will surely be read carefully. (Imagine receiving one from a certain j.spolsky@se.com.) All they *can* do is send a friendly mail, asking for certain phrasing to be adjusted, and mentioning that their current wording invites questions that **makes their product look bad** on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @RadLexus Yes, you can ask nicely, which if I understand correctly, *worked* in this case. But that isn't a *reliable* solution to this problem as its always possible that the other side can simply ignore the request, or say "no". This answer simply approaches the issue from a logical problem solving perspective. In terms of a reliable solution to the problem, whether or not someone *should* wrongly direct traffic to SO is irrelevant, unless there are legal measures that can be taken, which considering the national diversity of programming libraries and groups, is highly unlikely.

Comment: @Viziionary It's reliable enough for larger companies to take seriously. Smaller companies that do this will not have such a large influence here, so it matters far less. Ultimately just saying "let it be" is a licence to everyone to start doing the same thing.

Comment: You obviously can't force anyone to do anything. But the point is that, if such questions will not be well received on Stack Overflow, it is in the best interest of the company *not* to encourage their users to ask those types of questions here. No company gets very far by pissing off its users.